# How to mock a node module that doesn't exist yet?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

**no-such-module.ts**

```
declare module 'no-such-module' {
    export function sum(a: number, b: number): number;
}
```

**sum.ts**

```
import { sum } from 'no-such-module';

export const func = (a: number, b: number) => sum(a, b);
```

**sample.test.ts**

```
jest.mock('no-such-module');
const { sum } = require('no-such-module');

sum.mockImplementation((a,b) => a+b);

describe('sample test', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
        expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

**Error**

```
Cannot find module 'no-such-module' from 'sample.test.ts'

    > 1 | jest.mock('no-such-module');
        |      ^
      2 | const { sum } = require('no-such-module');
      3 | 
      4 | sum.mockImplementation((a,b) => a+b);
```

Is it possible to mock a node module that doesn't exist yet? I declared a `no-such-module` in a ts file. I am trying to mock a function from the module.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
jest.mock('no-such-module', () => {
    return {
        sum: (a,b) => a+b
    };
}, { virtual: true });

const { sum } = require('no-such-module');
```

we need to pass options `{ virtual: true }` to jest.mock()

Comment: Is there a way to override the implementation of 'sum' inside each of out test. Because most of the time we want to test different scenarios for each test